# Using CORS in JQuery to fetch RSS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, cors

I am probably doing this all wrong... I kind of feel like I am flailing about with code...

I started with this:

```
function getData(){
//getting XML data
  $.get('http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss', function(d){
    //need to capture the data to process the data.
    //we are representing the data with the letter d
    console.log(d); //this method is good to see the structure of the data if you don't know it already
     $(d).find('item').each( function(){
        //find each item and do the following:
        var article = $(this);
        var title = article.find('title').text();
        var description = article.find('description').text();
        var guid = article.find('guid').text();
        var date = article.find('pubDate').text();
        var theText = '<article><h3><a href="'+guid+'">'+title+'</a></h3><p>Published on:'+date+'</p><p>'+description+'</p>';
        $('#content').append(theText);
       }); //end each
     }) //end anon func
  }//end getData();
getData();
```

And I got the following: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Okay.... so I looked all over the web. I found an extension on chrome that if enabled lets it work - but that won't help me for a live website. Looked up and down the web for information on CORS and I do not understand the documentation. I get the impression that I have to pass header information but I'm not sure where or how.

I found this and tried it:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://rss.cnn.com",
   "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"content-type"            },
   url: "http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss"
  }).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    });
```

Here is the error message I get now:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

It might seem silly for me to ask, but is the requested resource the rss feed I am looking to get datafrom? Or is it my document. I've read so much on this that my head and eyes are spinning from confusion. Please help!

Thanks

Comment: It means than CNN does not allow `http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss` to be fetched using client-side JavaScript from any domain other than its own.

Comment: They would have to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header; there is nothing you can do other than request it through a server instead of directly in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The resource you are asking (the rss file) is in the CNN's server. However, they don't let you to access from your browser. That's why you get the CORS error. There are different ways of overcoming this problem such as using JSONP. However, still CNN has to enable jsonp in their server.

The only thing you can do is to enable  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the server side and then request.

Answer (score 1):

```
var requestOptions: RequestInit = {
    method: 'GET',
    redirect: 'follow'
  };
  const CORS_PROXY = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
  
  fetch(CORS_PROXY + "http://fetchrss.com/rss/5f56c6803c140278522985135f56c72f61579219a908f6e2.json", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Four year later update so feel free to remove if out of context. Try adding the CORS_PROXY bit as it worked for me. I found the fix in the rss-parse npm module docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser